# Is the condition that Span(S) $= V$ for $S$ to be a basis not redundant?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the condition that Span(S) $= V$ for $S$ to be a basis not redundant?

There are 2 conditions for a set of vectors S to be a basis right?

1) Linear independence.

2) Span(S) $= V$

But now say you are given a system of vectors with actual values and you need to see if it is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ for example.

To test for linear independence, you find a system of equations and see if the determinant of that is not equal to 0 then the system is linearly independent but you do the same thing to find if S spans V so why do you need both conditions

Comment: You are correct for the case where you have a set of exactly 3 vectors in $R^3$.  If Dim(V)=n and you have a set of n vectors, then you only need to check one of the two conditions.

Comment: What if you take fewer than $3$ vectors? Then the determinant doesn't make sense.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the set $\{(1,0)\}$ is linearly independent, but it does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$. So it is not a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a finite-dimensional vector space, it suffices to just check that the number of vectors in the basis is equal to the dimension and that the vectors are linearly independent.

However, both conditions are needed in the case of infinite-dimensional vector spaces.  The reason for this because if $A$ is an infinite set and $a \in A$, then $A$ and $A \setminus \{a\}$ have the same cardinality.  This is explains why a basis is defined the way it is.